# Choice analysis small sample size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, small-sample

I am looking for an appropriate statistical test for investigating significance of the differences between popularity of choices made by subjects. I would be also interested in investigating the impact of the sex of the subject on the choices made. I do realize that the sample size is small

The following experiment was performed:

7 subjects (3 Males, 4 Females) were given 5 items to choose from (all items were presented at the same time). There were 5 options to choose from (categorical data). Each subject had 4 repetitions. During some repetitions, subjects did not make any choice (NA). The number of successful repetitions per subjects (ID) is the following:

```
ID    Freq  
 1      2 
 2      3 
 3      3 
 4      2 
 5      2 
 6      3 
 7      3
```

The summary of the choices made is the following:

```
option     Freq  
    1      2    
    2      2    
    3      2    
    4      1    
    5     11    
 <NA>     10    
Total     28
```

Thanks.